# Is there a way to work on a Google Drive doc offline?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, offline

I'm going to be in an area with shotty internet connection. I would like to be working on a Google Drive doc but know it usually doesn't let you edit if it's not connected to the internet. Is there a way around this? I will be the only person working on it and it's not shared. If relevant I'm using Windows on a laptop with Firefox.

Comment: You can find your answer @ google help: [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102) and [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012). if it helps you I can turn it to an answer.

Comment: @marikamitsos that's only for the chorme browser. there is no "offline" section for me in firefox. but thanks, chrome is free.

Comment: I am afraid you need to switch (just for editing your docs) to Google Chrome. As per the documentation "_Offline access is only available in the Google Chrome browser._". Sorry :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you need to switch (just for editing your docs) to Google Chrome.

As per the documentation found [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012) :

> "*Offline access is only available in the Google Chrome browser.*"

Once on Chrome, under the corresponding settings, you can enable offline editing per file:
[image: per file]

OR for all files:
[image]